# Ideal background-validation-millis value for Pool size about 50

Tags: java, oracle11g, datasource, jndi, jboss5.x

We are using jboss enterprise application server 5.x for our application
Also we are using jboss datasource `*-ds.xml` to have a connection pool.
Below is the datasource xml file

```
<datasources>
        <local-tx-datasource>
                <jndi-name>myappDS</jndi-name>
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521:sid</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <user-name>usr</user-name>
                <password>pass</password>
                <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
                <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
                <failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>
                <maxReconnects>50</maxReconnects>
                <initialTimeout>15</initialTimeout> 
                <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                <background-validation-millis>150000</background-validation-millis>
                <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                <!--
                        corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml
                        (optional)
                -->
                <metadata>
                        <type-mapping>Oracle11g</type-mapping>
                </metadata>
        </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Now here as you see we are using background connection validation using a query.
My understanding is jboss will try to execute the validation query for each of the connection currently in pool to validate the connections.

 **1.** Is my understanding correct?

 **2.** If yes then what should be the ideal `<background-validation-millis>` value provided my max pool size is 50 and the db will be restarted only during weekend. We introduced this validation because whenever the DB was **restarted** we had to restart our Jboss server otherwise it was not able to connect automatically to database.
Let me know if the question is not clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is clear and your understanding is correct afaik. I'm sorry I can't help with point 2, because that's exactly what I'm also searching for.

Comment: Wow this is still a problem after almost 9 years :)

Comment: Yeah. These systems last for a lot of time :D

Answer (score 0):

The sql specified by the configuration setting check-valid-connection-sql will be run before a  connection is returned to the user when he is checking out a connection from the pool. The background-validation-millis clause makes sure the validation runs in a separate thread and specifies the interval of the check.

Comment: do you know what ` <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>` does?? I think you should read d jboss documentation.. i thought this clause will prevent the validation during connection check out.

Comment: It simply says that the check is invoked in the background thread.